# Unable to list or write to CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

With the code I have below, I am reading a CSV file into a dictionary and I have the field names set in the `'fieldname'` variable. Each field name has corresponding values in the CSV file.

When printing each field name, two give me

> "KeyError: 'Month'" and "KeyError: 'Year'"

All others display properly. Not sure what may be causing this. Also, when trying to write the contents of each field name into a new file I get an error `wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames`

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'"
```

Code:

```
import csv

with open('mmns.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('c1.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['Day', 'Month', 'Year', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',')

        for line in csv_reader:
            print(line['c1'])
            csv_writer.writerow(line['c1'])
```

Comment: check the keys of `line` / first line of your input file

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that white spaces would cause issues like that. Do you have any tips for the writing the contents to another file?

Comment: Bbrown: You haven't shown an example of the input file in your question, so I'm not sure what you mean about white spaces causing issues. One possibly helpful thing you could do would be to add a `skipinitialspace=True` argument to the `csv.DictWriter` constructor call, which may get rid of at least some of it.

Comment: @Bbrown is this issue resolved?

Comment: It is not, I am still having issues writing each field name to a separate file.